# Postman storing collection variable JWT token after user logins from response

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, jwt, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm trying to store a postman **collection** variable for a JWT token after a user logins. I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError | Invalid or unexpected token

For reference this is what I've been using for the `tests`

```
var data = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set(“token”, data.token);
```

response from POST on user login

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVjYjRhN2E0Njg5MzBiN2FkOTI0MzUwZCIsIm5hbWUiOiJWaW5jZW50IFRhbmciLCJpYXQiOjE1NTUzNzEzMDYsImV4cCI6MTU1NTM3NDkwNn0.P3V2YRcAAkZugJnCZ-GYFcCqFHDn4ei45kh5MgO2r0s"
}
```

Picture of POST request for user to login

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the solution.

I copied the snippet from a blog but the blog rendered the **quotations** as Unicode characters instead of just regular quotes.

Original statement:

> pm.environment.set(“token", data.token);

Revised:

> pm.environment.set(“token", data.token);